# Commute finite and infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_{ij}\ge 0$ real numbers. Is it true that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} a_{ij}= \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \sum_{i=1}^n  a_{ij} $$

I am pretty sure it is true, but I can't prove it. Any hint - or counterexample?

Comment: I think the Monotone Convergence Theorem is of interest here.

Comment: I know, but I dont want to use any measure theorem. Is there an elementary proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $b_i,c_i\geq 0$ are sequences then
$$\lim_{i\to\infty}{(b_i+c_i)}=\lim_{i\to\infty}{b_i}+\lim_{i\to\infty}{c_i}$$
Applying this finitely many times gives us the result. (Note that the assumption of nonnegativity, or at least nonnegativity of the product of the two sequences, is required for this to hold in general).

Comment: Thanks very much, it was easy, I'm just dumb.

Comment: @AngeloRendina You're welcome.