# Commutativity of finite and infinite summation operators

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Dear mathematics community,

I am trying to understand the following equality:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} a_{ij} = \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}$$

with $a_{ij} \geq 0$. I intentionally used the same notation as in this thread: [Commute finite and infinite sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047397/commute-finite-and-infinite-sum), but I cannot make sense of the answer given in the other thread, saying that for sequences $b_i,c_i \geq 0$ we have
$$\lim_{i\to\infty} (b_i + c_i) = \lim_{i\to\infty} b_i + \lim_{i\to\infty} c_i$$
I see the intuition behind it, as it relates something infinite to finite sums, but how can I use it to show the equality of the summation above? I made an attempt to prove it:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}$$
Now let $b_j(n) := \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m b_j(n) = \sum_{j=1}^m \lim_{n\to\infty} b_j(n) = \sum_{j=1}^m \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}.$$

Is this correct? It seems like I inevitably have to use

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}$$

which is where I am uncertain, because of the limit operator. Does this hold? And if so, why?

Thank you very much in advance, any help is appreciated!

P.S.:
Me being unsure is enforced by me wondering why somebody would make such a fuss about proving
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$$
by using column sums, row sums or defining functions (as in Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, page 175) and whatever, if you could just write, using and assuming that $a_{ij}$ satisfies the conditions of the theorem on monotone convergence
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n  \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}$$
now switching summation operators
$$ = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m  \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^\infty  \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}  \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty  \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$$
?

Comment: Are you familiar with the distinction between absolute and conditional convergence?

Comment: @hardmath: Well, a little bit, but seemingly not enough, if this is the key to my problem. I know (and claim to have more or less understood) some basic results, e.g. that if a series converges unconditionally, then it also converges absolutely.

Comment: I thought it might be a good starting point to bring up because you are careful to mention $b_i,c_i \ge 0$ but make no explicit claim about $a_{ij}$ being nonnegative.

Comment: @hardmath: Yes, you are right, I should have mentioned it in the beginning, not at the very end (when requiring $a_{ij}$ to satisfy the conditions of the monotone convergence theorem). I changed that. I see that $a_{ij} \geq 0$ is necessary for being able to switch the summation operators when there is no limit in front, but I cannot see what more to derive from it for determining whether switching the summation operators is valid given that there is a limit operator in front.